# ifstream cannot open file

Tags: c++, ifstream

There are other topics similar to this one, but none with quite the same issue and none of those resolutions are working for me.
Here is the opening code I am working with:

```
ifstream inputFile;
 string filename;

 cout << " Tablerock Member Services" << endl;
 cout << "***************************\n\n" << endl;
 cout << " Please enter the name of the member file: ";
 cin >> filename;

 inputFile.open(filename);
```

The filename is MemberInfo.txt (I unhid the tail end and I did try a direct path, MemberInfo, MemberInfo.txt, and MemberInfo.txt.txt)

It is the the current directory, and no matter what I try, it still won't open.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
Here is the full code so far(including items you probably don't need.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int FindInfo();

int main()
{
 //declare
 int choice = 0;
 char ans = '\0';
 auto stuff = 0;
 const int SEARCH_CHOICE = 1;
 const int ADD_CHOICE = 2;
 const int EDIT_CHOICE = 3;
 const int DISPLAY_CHOICE = 4;
 const int QUIT_CHOICE = 5;

 ifstream inputFile;
 string filename;

 cout << " Tablerock Member Services" << endl;
 cout << "***************************\n\n" << endl;
 cout << " Please enter the name of the member file: ";
 cin >> filename;

 inputFile.open(filename.c_str());

 if(inputFile)
 {
    do
     {

     cout << "\n";
     cout << " 1. Find a member's information" << endl;
     cout << " 2. Add a member to the database" << endl;
     cout << " 3. Edit a member's information" << endl;
     cout << " 4. Display all records" << endl;
     cout << " 5. Quit" << endl;

     cout << " Please choose an option from the menu:";    
     cin >> choice;

     switch(choice)
     {
        case SEARCH_CHOICE:
        FindInfo();
        cout << " Would you like to choose again?";
        cin >> ans;
        break;

        case ADD_CHOICE:
        cout << " You chose option 2." << endl;
        cout << " Would you like to choose again?";
        cin >> ans;
        break;

        case EDIT_CHOICE:
        cout << " You chose option 3." << endl;
        cout << " Would you like to choose again?";
        cin >> ans;
        break;

        case DISPLAY_CHOICE:
        cout << " You chose option 4." << endl;
        cout << " Would you like to choose again?";
        cin >> ans;
        break; 

        case QUIT_CHOICE:
        cout << " Press Q to exit the program or y/Y to select another option.";
        cin >> ans;
        break;
         }//end switch
     }while( ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');
 }

 else while (inputFile == false)
 {
     cout << "There was an error opening the file. \n Please enter the filename: ";
     cin >> filename;
     inputFile.open("filename");
 }

 return 0;
}

int FindInfo()
{
    const int SIZE = 21;
    char lname[SIZE];
    char ans = '0';


    cout << "\n\n Search for a member:" << endl;
    cout << "\n Please enter the last name of the member you are trying to find." << endl;
    cout << " Last Name: ";
    cin >> lname;    
    cout << " You entered " << lname << "." << endl;
    cout << " Is this correct? (y/n)";
    cin >> ans;

    if( ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
    {
        cout << " Great! Please wait while we find the member in our database..." << endl;
    }

    else while( ans == 'n' || ans == 'N')
    {
        cout << " Please enter the last name of the member you are trying to find." << endl;
        cout << " Last Name: ";
        cin >> lname;    
        cout << " You entered " << lname << "." << endl;
        cout << " Is this correct? (y/n)";
        cin >> ans;

        if( ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
        {
            cout << " Great! Please wait while we find the member in our database..." << endl;
        }

    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++11 adds support for using `std::string` in the [`open` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open). If your compiler doesn't support that you're missing out on a ton of new features so it's worth upgrading if possible.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for this project.

Comment: Ideally you can switch to 2015 and take advantage of not only the improvements in C++11, but C++14. There's [a lot of new stuff there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) worth checking out.

Comment: Define "cannot open file". What actually happens? What do you see?

Comment: I run program and when it prompts me for file, no matter which directory the file is in, or name of the file, for that matter, it cannot locate the file. i get my error message (which you can find in the last else of main.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code.

1. In a while loop you have `inputFile.open("filename");` instead of `inputFile.open(filename);` (quotes).
2. This while loop should be probably before line `if(inputFile)`. Otherwise there is no chance to go back when you give the wrong file name.

(I'd also change `while (inputFile == false)` to `while (!inputFile)`.)

Moreover, when prompted, a user should give the path to the file relative to the directory from which he executes the program. Otherwise, it wouldn't find it.

Comment: Okay, fixed those errors (thank you) and even with a direct path it won't find the file

Comment: Hmm. I compiled your code and it works. Did you try creating a new file, even empty? If a file is read protected, it wouldn't find it either. Also if you are running the program from IDE, try running it from a console.

Answer (score -1):

If you convert your filename to a c style string, fstream.open() should work on it. You can use .c_str() for the conversion. At least this is what I do when I convert strings to c style strings.

```
inputFile.open(filename.c_str());
```

Here is the documentation on [ifstream's open function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/)

Comment: Would I need to include the c string modifier to my variable declaration as well?

Comment: Nope, just the conversion in the open function should do it.

Comment: I just tried to run it with the mod and no dice. Any other suggestions?

Comment: And you're include <string> also?

Comment: Yeah. Here's my full code. (I know, using namespace std; is horrible practice, but I only leave it till the end and then i call individual std::cin/cout/whatever items. I'll edit the original.

Comment: OP does not report a compilation error. Granted, OP is extremely vague and unclear.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean. I've never asked the c++ community for help before, as such, I am unfamiliar with what you need to know. When I run the program, i am given the opportunity to enter my filename, but, under no cirucmstances that I have discovered thus far, the program cannot locate the file. It is in the current directive, and I've made sure that my file extensions are clear. I've tried locating it via a direct path, and still, no such luck. I have tried the suggestions above, yet nothing seems to work. Is there anything else I can add to be less vague? I'm at a loss.

Comment: So I don't know if you still need help, but I changed your if statement:     `if(inputFile)` to `if(inputFile.good())`. I also changed your `else while(inputfile == false)` to `else while(!inputfile.good())` and was able to compile and run your code.